# 960 grid system - layout breaking in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Here is a link to the page:

When viewing the index page of this website in IE6 I am finding that a particular section of the web page layout breaks. Sadly my manager wants the site to hold it's appearance in IE6. The 'Latest Tweets' and 'Contact Us' should run in line horizontally with one another, however 'Contact Us' is displaying below 'Latest tweets' in IE6. I believe the issue is due to the fact that the `.grid` classes have floats applied to them. However I have tried to clear these floats where possible. Here is my stripped down markup structure where the layout is breaking including my clears.

```
<div class="grid_4 alpha">
    <h2 class="text250 margbottom NG">Latest Tweets</h2>
</div>  

<div class="grid_8 omega">
    <h2 class="text250 margbottom NG">Contact Us</h2>
    <div class="grid_4 alpha">  
        <!--content-->                  
    </div>
    <div class="grid_4 omega">
        <!--content-->  
    </div>  

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div> 

    <div class="grid_4 alpha">
        <!--content-->  
    </div>
    <div class="grid_4 omega">
        <!--content-->  
    </div>  

    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>     
</div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

Here is an image of the issue:

Comment: IE6? Seriously? 2 years ago, IE6 usage was less than 1%. Stop beating dead horse, just upgrade.

Comment: It's not me I am the junior in my team following orders, and my manager is still obsessed with these things.

Comment: Just show him this [Microsoft website](http://www.ie6countdown.com/champions.aspx)

Comment: Grrr. I love it when project requirements mean developers end up spending more time making it work in IE6 than will ever be spent by real visitors actually using IE6. Meh. Your manager really needs to start living in the real world.

Comment: Seriously, [IE6 is now at 0.1% usage in the UK](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-GB-monthly-200911-201303). The few people who are still using it obviously don't care about sites looking rubbish because nobody is writing sites that support it any more. If your site is even usable in IE6 you should consider it job done and move on. Trying to make it look the same as other browsers is an exercise in futility, and will hold you back from being able to use modern features. Even IE7 isn't considered worth supporting these days, let alone IE6.

Comment: by the way, since this is a CSS question and the answer is likely in the CSS, you should probably post some CSS code in the question.  :-)

Comment: I hate my manager and want to leave my job because of his dogma. You are all right in what you say and I can't wait until I am freelance and won't care about IE6 at all.

Comment: Unless the audience for your website is China then I wouldn't bother

Comment: It's startling to see so many people commenting to mock the IE6 support but no actual help offered.  I'm here because I have to support IE6/IE7 -- 0.1% usage for IE6 in the UK, sure, for the general population.  How about IE7 usage in the NHS, for example?  Extremely prevalent (fortunately IE6 is finally dropping off even there).  What about if you need your site to run on POS computers?  Hello IE6!  It's horrid to support, but there are still plenty of developers who don't have the luxury of mocking it yet.